# El Captain Split Screen on Yosemite

Tags: macos, window-manager

Apple has recently announced El Captain in their WWDC. One of the features announced was split screen mode.

Since I am not an developer I have to wait until July to have access to some of the features. Is there a tweak I can install on Yosemite to gain the SplitScreen View?

Note:
I have BetterTouchTool however that only allows for window snapping. I want the resizable feature that El Captain has.

Comment: If it was already possible in Yosemite there would be little need to advertise it as a new feature for El Capitan ...

Comment: @Tetsujin Apple advertise new features in the OS that have been pulled from third-party apps all the time. For example, when introducing the new Spotlight in Yosemite which provided the same UI and similar features to Alfred/Launchbar.

Comment: @Tetsujin BetterTouchTool snaps the windows side by side. Apple has implemented it too. It makes it easier for users who don't know about it to use it. Also when people get a new Mac they don't have to install the software they did before. They also don't have to remember to get it to start at startup. It could also help with performance and battery life of the system.

Comment: My point still stands. It's not currently possible.

Answer (score 1):

Divvy or another third party app is your only solution. The code to do this isn't on Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest Cinch, it is super easy to setup and use and is entirely free!
[Click the "Download" button](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/)